# PostgreSQL locks after 6th execution of the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-9.2, locks

PostgreSQL version: Postgres Plus Advanced Server 9.2
Operating system: Windows 7/8

I have a stored procedure which acts like it follows:
1. Clears **table1**
2. Selects from a view (*same view always*) based on a couple of parameters passed in the *WHERE* clause (*always same parameters for the sake of the example*)
3. Inserts into **table1** the results of the select above.

The body of the procedure looks as follows:

```
BEGIN

    PERFORM clear_table1(p_session_id);

    INSERT INTO table1 (session_id, id1, adress, x, y)
    SELECT p_session_id, id1, adress, x, y
        FROM myview
        WHERE (CONDITION)
            AND (CONDITION)
            AND (CONDITION)
            AND (lower(adress) LIKE lower(p_adress) OR p_adress IS NULL)
            LIMIT 6000;
END;
```

First 5 times (always 5 times) I run the exact same query with the exact same parameters, it runs as expected. Next time (6th time) it runs for an enormous amount of time, something like .. tens of minutes.

```
select * from myfunction('session_id',NULL,NULL,'%adress%')
```

In **Server Status** view from PostgreSQL Manager, I observed a number of locks added for the tables in which I insert **along with the tables from which the view is populated**

Could anyone with PostgreSQL experience tell me if there's some kind of setting to fix this behaviour **OR** did this or something similar happen to someone else using PG?

**Thanks!!!**

*Later edit*:  - the issue always occurs **only** when the 6 invocations are made from the **same session**   - we do not explicitly commit at the end of the stored procedure

Comment: 1) Do you commit between invocations? 2) are the 6 invocations issued from different sessions ?

Comment: Please see the later edit

Comment: Why do you use a function just to clear the table? Why not just `delete from table`;` or `truncate table`;` ?

Comment: Clear the table using a function because I want to delete only the records which are relevant for the provided session_id, not all the records in that table.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: You're using JDBC with the default prepare threshold.

See if disabling server-side prepare makes the issue go away. See [the PgJDBC docs](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/server-prepare.html).

Failing that, if the slow call is within the function: try enabling `auto_explain` with processing of function bodies enabled. Then see if the plan changes for some reason on the 6th invocation.

Comment: Had to look it up..."with processing of function" SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = 1;

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a really old question, but yesterday I had just the exactly same problem.

It's tricky to realize it, cause it's always after the sixth time that it occurs.

I'm not able to explain the cause, however I was able to fix it.

In my case I had to change the part where it was

```
SELECT (sum(coalesce(debito.vl_conta,0)) ) ...
```

to

```
execute 'SELECT (sum(coalesce(debito.vl_conta,0)) ) ...
```

and that's it. But answering here just in case someone else suffers it too, or maybe explain why it happens.

Thanks,